# Is there a way of exporting fstab info for device which is currently mounted?

Tags: linux, unix, mount, fstab

Does there exist any tool which can tell you what the fstab line for a mount should be? Ie. it looks at something which has been mounted manually and tells you the line which you would have to add to `/etc/fstab` to have the same mount be persistent.

I understand that this might have to be a 'heuristic', or in other words a guess, as to options etc. But it seems like it would nonetheless be very useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see some information about currently mounted devices by looking at the contents of `/etc/mtab` (the syntax is quite similar to the one of `/etc/fstab`).
You should find some useful information about mount options as well.

Otherwise, you can use a simple "fstab generator" like this one:

http://epistel.no/fstab/

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `/etc/mtab`. It contains list of all currently mounted systems with their parameters. From what I see on my Ubuntu system those lines can be directly copied to `/etc/fstab`.

Another place worth looking is `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: The advantage of `/proc/mounts` is that it is generated by the kernel and thus doesn't get out of sync with reality. The advantage of `/etc/mtab` is that it sometimes contains some additional details which the `mount` command keeps track of but the kernel does not keep track of.